# Custom table in ASP.NET Identity

Tags: asp.net, database, asp.net-identity

I created a new table in the database called UserProfile. This table contains, id, name, surname, and email. However, when I try to login, it will not let me log in with email. Only allowed to log in with a username.

So how can I only login with Email from UserProfile table? Instead logging with UserName in AspNetUsers table.?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Identity are you using? Sounds like 1.0, a simple solution would be to update to Identity version 2.0.

Or else you can try writing your own method with in IdentityExtensions class as explained in http://anthonychu.ca/post/aspnet-identity-20---logging-in-with-email-or-username/